# How DB2(v10.5.0.5) add auto increment column to an exists table

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to add an auto increment column in an existing table of `DB2`.

DB2 version is `v10.5.0.5`.

Following is my query:

```
alter table DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND 
ADD COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND ALTER COLUMN id 
set generated always as identity (start with 1);
```

but I got following error:

```
"com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: ALTER TABLE "DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND" 
specified attributes for column "ID" that are not compatible with the existing 
column.. SQLCODE=-190, SQLSTATE=42837, DRIVER=4.13.127"
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know about DB2 (it's might simply not allow adding a sequence to an existing table), but did you try to combine both ALTER?: `alter table DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND 
ADD COLUMN id INTEGER NOT NULL generated always as identity (start with 1);`

Comment: This will still lead to errors, but the solution is given below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must drop the column DEFAULT value first.
This is mentioned in the description of [SQL0190N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0190n):

> If SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expression) is specified, but the column
>   is already defined with a form of generation (default, identity, or
>   expression) and there is no corresponding DROP in the same statement.

```
ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND 
ALTER COLUMN id drop default;

ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND ALTER COLUMN id 
set generated always as identity (start with 1);
```

Comment: Your answer helped me solve this problem. Now I have successfully added auto-increasing ID to the table through the following three steps:

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ADD COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;` 

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ALTER COLUMN ID DROP DEFAULT; `

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ALTER COLUMN ID SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1);`

Comment: After setting the new default value, execute this to replace old defaults:

`UPDATE DB2INST1.AAA_BJ_BOND SET ID = DEFAULT WHERE ID = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Now I have successfully added auto-increasing ID to the table through the following three steps:

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ADD COLUMN ID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;`

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ALTER COLUMN ID DROP DEFAULT;`

`ALTER TABLE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT ALTER COLUMN ID SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1);`

Comment: Don't forget about setting unique value to all existing rows:

`UPDATE DB2INST1.AAA_SEAT SET ID = DEFAULT;`